# What (and how) UHF receiver should I buy?

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, wireless, lavalier, radio

I am in a situation where a UHF mic is being used to transmit audio to a speaker with a built in receiver. In this case, the speaker in question is a Pyle PPHP1241WMU. The actual transmitter has no branding or model number, but I found that the frequency is marked as 662.6 MHz.

What I'd like to do is be able to record the audio from the mic to an external device using a separate receiver. However, I don't know what frequency is needed or even what to buy. Shedding any light on the situation would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual](https://pyleusa.com/products/pphp1241wmu) for this device states it provides stereo line out (>250mV) on a pair of RCA (phono) connectors. If the microphone signal is routed to the line out you can record that with no need for a receiver. (I'd expect the microphone signal should be available on the line out but the "manual" is very short on details.)

The microphones are VHF although the actual frequency and modulation type aren't stated.

> a Pyle PPHP1241WMU. The actual transmiter has no branding or specs or model number, so I know almost nothing about it.

I found the manufacturer's documentation (such as it is) just by googling the brand and part number. The radio microphones (transmitters) are bundled with the main unit so are not documented separately.

Comment: Thanks! So if I just hook up an RCA to 1/8" converter I (should) get audio out? This sounds easy enough that it's worth trying.

Comment: Also, pretty sure the mic's are UHF, because it's marked UHF on the back of the speaker and I've discovered they run at 662.6 MHz.

Comment: "pretty sure the mic's are UHF" The [website](https://pyleusa.com/products/pphp1241wmu) has a picture of the back panel with a section labelled "VHF WIRELESS MICROPHONES". Pyle might have swapped to UHF mics since taking the website photos. The next step ought to be to try recording from the line out (via whatever adapters you need) rather than finding a scanner or SDR.

Comment: Works. The mic signal is present on the RCA outputs.

Comment: Another win for Reading The Fine Manual.

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching this from the wrong direction.
You are not going to be able to successfully reverse engineer this RF link. Could be any frequency, even 2.4GHz. Could be any modulation. You are not going to be able to find out without a significant amount of effort.

Solution is to replace the RF link with your own. Give the talent a different radio mic, one which you have control over. Take the output for the receiver into your recorder and split the output for a hard-wired input to the speaker.

If this isn't possible, replace the speaker.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've updated my answer because I've found the frequency of the transmitter, but I don't think that would make a difference to you. Unfortunately, In my case I cannot change neither the transmitter nor the speaker, only hook on to what's existing.